# D3 function to parse the date not working

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6

I have a d3 visualisation that works fine with the current stable release (`3.x`) however I wanted to implement the [Pan & Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2a39a768b1d4bc00a09650edef75ad39) function so I upgraded to `4.alpha`.

This threw a lot of bugs as the syntax has changed. I updated the variable names, however there is one remaining bug pertaining to the second line of the following code:

```
function type(d) {
   d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
   d.Flux = +d.Flux;
   return d;
}
```

Opening up the page source via the browser, I see that `formatDate.parse is not a function.` The visualisation is currently not rendering.

I have tried combing the D3 `4.alpha` [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3), to no avail.

Further up in the code, `formatDate` is defined as follows:

```
var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%d-%b-%y");
```

I am happy to post the original code, its about 70 lines long, and a bit hacky tho:

---

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1400// - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1400// - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%d-%b-%y");
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Flux); });
var svg = d3.selectAll("#ExoPlanet, #ExoPlanet2").append("svg")
    .attr("width", '90%')
    .attr("height", '70%')
    .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed)) ;
function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + transform.applyX(d[0]) + "," + transform.applyY(d[1]) + ")";
  });
}

d3.tsv("/FluxTime.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Flux; }));
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 2.0)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Flux); })
        .attr("stroke", "#CE9A76");
});
function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date));
  d.Flux = +d.Flux;
  return d;
```

}

A screenshot of the first 8 entries in the dataset:

[image: datums]

Comment: Thanks! the error has changed to `can't find variable: parse` . I have other javascript on the page and that renders fine however. I am using jQuery 3.0.

Comment: :-) different error now: `can't find variable: timeParse` via the docs I also just tried `tsvParse`, didn't work either. Also tried `formatDate.tsvParse(d.date)`, no luck.

Comment: i posted the full code for clarity

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the dataset.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In D3 3.5, you could parse just the way you did, setting the time format...

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");
```

...and then using this time format to parse:

```
d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
```

But, using D3 4.0, you have to parse dates in a different way, using `timeParse`:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
```

And, then, modifying your accessor function:

```
function type(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.Flux = +d.Flux;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: ugly ugly version 4

Comment: can you please advice me a good resource on version 4? The documentation is the most poor documentation I have seen so far.

Comment: @ArslArsl I agree that the d3 version 4 API is a bit confusing for those who don't have familiarity with d3, but for those with knowledge of d3 version 3 it's quite easy to navigate to the correct point. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other resources regarding version 4.

Comment: Some d3.v3 and v4 comparisons https://keithpblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/upgrading-d3-from-v3-to-v4/

Comment: @Ars!Ars! One has to wonder if the measure of good documentation is whether it is easy for those already familiar with the subject matter to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

The api has changed. For me the solution was:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m")
parseTime("2018-09")
=> Sat Sep 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

If you want to go the other way, Date class to string:

```
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m")
formatTime(new Date)
=> "2020-09"
```